# Testing booted method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am using Laravel Cashier with Stripe, and I am trying to cover the the following lines in my tests, so far I tried mocking but that did not work, I was wondering what is the best practice to test them

```
use function Illuminate\Events\queueable;
 
/**
 * The "booted" method of the model.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected static function booted()
{
    static::updated(queueable(function ($customer) {
        if ($customer->hasStripeId()) {
            $customer->syncStripeCustomerDetails();
        }
    }));
}
```

The code is taken from https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/billing#syncing-customer-data-with-stripe

Comment: This can easily be achieved, but i need to see the code entry point of what you want to test, especially how you get your Customer object to update.

Comment: @mrhn thanks for your response, here is the full Model, please notice that I removed the booted method because I could not test it and replaced it with t an event, listener, and a job if there is an easy method to test I will replace back the booted method 

https://github.com/mabumusa1/saas/blob/dev/app/Models/Account.php

Comment: Where you call the model, to properly mock it i need the entry point

Comment: like where you call $customer->save();

Comment: Thanks @mrhn, I make the call here
https://github.com/mabumusa1/saas/blob/dev/app/Http/Controllers/BillingController.php#L44

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa to test this you have to "feature" test it, you cannot/should not "unit" tests

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes of course, how to test it?

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa if it is a feature test, then you need to trigger what is using that part of the code, if it is reading a model and it is just doing so because a controller calls it, then feature test the controller and expect this to happen (so the code run), if it is just inside a model, maybe you can do a unit test updating a single field of your model and see if, after it was updated, if you have the stripe code run, etc.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I tried this approach but the code coverage test kept saying I did not hit the lines inside the if statement

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa I see you have `queueable`, I have never used that but I assume it will dispatch it to the queue, so what you can check is if you have `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync`, so it should dispatched and run it at the moment you call that, can you check your `QUEUE_CONNECTION` value? [This](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/695d6dc41c1db56698848452c47065ba89e4d3d6/src/Illuminate/Events/QueuedClosure.php#L113-L124) is what `queueable` does, maybe you can play with the `Event::fake()`, but I am not 100% sure right now.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I tried to fake an event, that worked but I could not cover the lines inside the queuable event. because the fake event suppress the execution of the event

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa yeah, if you fake the event you are not going to trigger it, that is why you need to do a feature test, but it is more complex than it seems, you can encapsulate that function inside a service but still

Comment: @matiaslauriti I had to make an event, listener, and a job to do the coverage of the code, I could not figure anyway to do it

Comment: I came up with an answer see if that helped you. Alternatively couldn't you just fake the queue instead of the events and that would help? Anyways, i have an answer to how in general i would mock these kind of calls. But the queueable, makes it more complex to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using a partial mock, `Laravel` has a helper for that method. Since you are actually using correct dependency injection, this would be my approach. It requires the queue setting in `phpunit` to be sync.

```
public function test_update_customer()
{
    $account = Account::factory()->create(['stripe_id' => 'fake']);

    $this->partialMock(Account::class, function ($mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('syncStripeCustomerDetails')
            ->once();
    });

    $response = $this->actingAs($someUser)
        ->put(route('billing.update', $account), [
            'name' => 'Some name',
            'email' => 'Another email',
        ]);

    $response->assertOk();
}
```